# Perforce Client showing timestamps of Server which is in different Timezone, Can the p4 client automatically convert the time for local timezone?

Tags: perforce

My P4 server is in different Timezone and I am located in different timezone so my client workspace is in different timezone than the server, when I run the following command
*
p4 changes -s submitted -m5 -t*

It shows the submit times that of server timezone and not the client timezone, Is there a way client can translate times automatically for the local timezone so I don't have to do math in the head.

I wonder why this timezone conversion is not default like in SVN?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to have the command-line client render the timestamp in the local timezone.  The client is very "thin"; when you see a formatted message at the command line, it's almost always being rendered by the server (meaning that if the message includes a date, it's using the server's timezone) and then sent to the client.

If you run a command in tagged mode (-Ztag at the CLI, or by setting the "tag" protocol if you use the API), you get the Unix-style timestamp, which is then easy to render in the local timezone if you're writing your own client app.  But the `p4` CLI itself does not implement this.

Comment: Thanks, If true, Its probably serious limitation in the client features. I don't need the timestamps for script but everytime I run 'p4 changes -s submitted -t'  I hate to do timezone math in my head. There is no solution to this?